# Entity Framework "Empty insert statement"

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, dbcontext, entity-framework-5, notsupportedexception

I am using entity framework code first with dotConnect for MySQL.

I get the following error when I call `context.SaveChanges()` after adding an object to the context:

> **DbUpdateException**:
>   An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
>
> Inner Exception:
>   UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
>
> Inner Exception: 
>   EntityCommandCompilationException: An error occurred while preparing the command definition. See the inner exception for details."}
>
> Inner Exception:
>   NotSupportedException: {"Empty insert statement."}

when saving the `DbContext` after I added an item to the `DbContext`

**The weird part is that when I add all its content its added successfully, but when I add the object itself I get this error.**

This line of code fails:

```
context.TournamentTables.Add(tournamentTable);
```

While this one works perfectly:

```
tournamentTable.Columns.ForEach(column =>
                                   {
                                       column.Cells.ForEach((cell) => context.TournamentCells.Add(cell));
                                       context.TournamentColumns.Add(column);

                                   });
```

Here is the object I try to add:

```
public class TournamentTable //: IEnumerable<TournamentColumn>
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int? Id { get; set; }

        public List<TournamentColumn> Columns { get; set; }

        public TournamentTable()
        {
            Columns = new List<TournamentColumn>();
        }

        public void AddColumn(int index, TournamentColumn column)
        {
            Columns.Insert(index, column);
        }

        public void RemoveColumn(int index)
        {
            Columns.RemoveAt(index);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Add a tournament cell at the top of the column.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="column"></param>
        public void AddColumn(TournamentColumn column)
        {
            Columns.Add(column);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the tournament column at the index specified.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="index"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [NotMapped]
        public TournamentColumn this[int index]
        {
            get { return Columns[index]; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the tournament cell at the index specified.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="columnIndex"></param>
        /// <param name="cellIndex"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [NotMapped]
        public TournamentCell this[int columnIndex, int cellIndex]
        {
            get { return Columns[columnIndex][cellIndex]; }
            set
            {

                Columns[columnIndex][cellIndex] = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Note that the Tournament Table Id is 0 by default, and if the Id is declared as "int?" than it will be null. I've tried both cases and also setting the id by myself and it still fails.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are adding the columns in the wrong way.

Basically, you don't need this:

```
tournamentTable.Columns.ForEach(column =>
{
    column.Cells.ForEach((cell) => context.TournamentCells.Add(cell));
    context.TournamentColumns.Add(column);
});
```

The Entity Framework does that for you. You only need to call `context.TournamentTables.Add(tournamentTable)` after you add all the columns to the tournamentTable.